# How to select a face (to add a texture) after importing from STL?

Tags: texturing, uv, faces, selection-tools

Just installed Blender 20 minutes ago (so please be nice!).  After importing an STL, how can I apply a texture?  I'm stuck even trying to select a face.  The help file says which icon to click but not how to get to a screen with that icon on it!

Could it be I need to do something with the imported STL before I can add textures?

My STL is here:
http://files.staging.x-rm.com/nick/House.stl

[image]

Comment: Using the [search tools](https://blender.stackexchange.com/search?tab=relevance&q=how%20to%20texture) here should yield some results..Mostly done in the [shader editor](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/shader_editor.html#shader-editor) in 2.8+ though. Please specify if you are wanting to use procedural or image textures.In your screenshot you are in vertex selection, in standard keymap 3 switches to face selection.

Comment: It is hard to teach you from scratch in a single post how to use blender.  watch a few videos to familiarize yourself with the interface and the main principles of the program: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLa1F2ddGya_-UvuAqHAksYnB0qL9yWDO6 You need to create a material, select the faces you want, and assign the material to them.

Comment: @Timaroberts Thanks. I'm not sure why each face is split into two triangles.  Would that be a problem with the STL or simply how blender works?

Comment: STL files usually consist of triangles. You can select your model in edit-mode, select all faces and use alt-J (Tris to quads) to convert (most of) the tris to quads. In simple models this works great, in higher res models you might end up with a few tris still.

Comment: @Jaco Thanks that worked!